# Multiple Apple pay merchant Ids on multiple developer accounts

Tags: ios, xcode, applepay

I have a project with a number of different build configurations, 4 for one developer account and 3 for another, each having production, alpha and beta build configurations and the first having a debug configuration. all 7 have different bundle ids

each developer account has apply pay setup with it’s own set of apple pay merchant ids.

Im getting the error that one build configuration’s provisioning profile is missing support for the other developer account’s merchant id and vice versa, they work fine if i delete the build configurations from the other developer account but when they are both in the project the error comes up.

Is there a workaround for this? am i missing something to tell the build configuration to only use it’s own merchant id?

Comment: Wow. A year passed and no replies. Ever found a solution? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Since the targets use the same `entitlements` to modify the capabilities such as `Apple Pay`, `Associated Domain` and `Push Notifications` etc.

My solutions:

1. Create the `.entitlements` files individually.
2. Targets → `Build Phases` → `Copy Bundle Resources` and link the correct `.entitlements` file.
3. Targets → `Build Settings` → `Signing` → `Code Signing Entitlements` and link the correct `.entitlements` file.
4. Back to `Signing & Capabilities`, now you could set it successfully :)

Hope it works for you!